# MySQL query problematic

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using PHP/MySQL and I have to create a new table from an existing one. Here's the problematic:

*Table1*:

```
photo_id   email          name_to   creation_date    link
1          foo1@bar.com   paul      2012-11-21       link1.com
2          foo2@bar.com   mark      2012-11-22       link2.com
3          foo1@bar.com   alex      2012-11-23       link3.com
4          foo1@bar.com   saul      2012-11-25       link4.com
5          foo1@bar.com   john      2012-11-26       link5.com
6          foo2@bar.com   math      2012-11-27       link6.com
7          foo3@bar.com   fred      2012-11-28       link7.com
```

In *Table1* the email is not unique, it can be repeated several times. Each link is different. With this data, I have to create a new table in which the email is unique with maximum of 3 links if there's more entries of one email (if so I need the data of the 3 latest entries).

So, in this case, *Table2* would be like:

```
email           link1        creation_date1    name_to1    link2        creation_date2    name_to2    link3        creation_date3    name_to3
foo1@bar.com    link5.com    2012-11-26        john        link4.com    2012-11-25        saul        link3.com    2012-11-23        alex
foo2@bar.com    link6.com    2012-11-27        math        link2.com    2012-11-22        mark
foo3@bar.com    link7.com    2012-11-28        fred
```

I know the GROUP_CONCAT feature but it's not really what I need here since the links would all be in the same column. Is it better to make a SELECT * FROM table1 and process the result into PHP arrays and after that create *Table2* or a unique MySQL query would do the trick? Or create multiple MySQL tables?

*Table1* is over 10 millions rows.

Any advice would be appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is PHP tagged? Are you using PHP?

Comment: Yes I'm using PHP/MySQL. The important part here is the MySQL query but is it better to do the process in PHP, that's one of my interrogations.

Comment: You could consider just taking the first 3 rows of each email address and sort them in descending order. That would give you the three newest links. You could then add that data into the new table. This is not one master SQL query solution, but I think its easier if you split up the steps with scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) select all unique emails.

2) For each email, take the first 3 rows with that email ordered by creation_date descending.

3) Use that data to insert into new table.

Whatchu think?

Comment: Yes, not sure if it's the most efficient way but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am not a huge SQL guru, that would know how to do that in all SQL queries.